# How to do I join selected columns in data frame with same col in excel object and update cell values in excel without converting excel to data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The current code I have is as below. I find this code not logical as I am not matching or joining the columns similar to pd.merge / join condition in database. Any alternate methods ?

```
Pseudo 
 Update xl.col1 = df.col1,
xl.col2 = df.col2
from abc.xls xl df
 where df.col1 = xl.col1 and df.col2 = xl.col2
 



 from openpyxl import load_workbook
    import pandas as pd
    wb = load_workbook('abc.xlsx')
    ws = wb['Sheet1']
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        cell = 'X%d'  % (index + 2) #cell to update in excel file
        ws[cell] = row['Col'] #row value from data frame
    wb.save('abc.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. Iterated through rows in excel and used loc in data frame.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook('wb.xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet1']
i=1
for row in ws.iter_rows():
     x=df.loc[df['col'] == row[2].value] #column to search 
     x_cell = 'X' + str(i)
     y_cell = 'Y' + str(i)
     ws[os_cell] = str(x['col1'].to_string())
     ws[sql_cell] = str(x['col2'].to_string())
     i=i+1
    
wb.save('wb.xlsx')
```